# trim before implode in php to get trimmed strings

Tags: php, arrays, string, implode

```
$array = array(' lastname ', ' email ', ' phone ');
$comma_separated = implode(" ", $array);

echo $comma_separated; // lastname  email  phone
```

I have the above code to combine or join string in PHP problem is if the element in array has extra in joined string it has extra space.

> Expected Result:Only one space between words in echo
>
> How to first trim each element in array before implode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use Following Code :

```
$array =  array(' lastname ', ' ',' email ', ' phone ');

$trimedarray=array_map("trim",$array);

$modifiedarray=array_values(array_filter($trimedarray)); 

$comma_separated = implode(" ", $modifiedarray);

echo $comma_separated;
```

Comment: hi what i asked is wrong i didnt notice a blank value in array what if `$array = array(' lastname ', ' ',' email ', ' phone '); how to only get element that is not empty 
`

Comment: $emptyelementsremovedarray = array_filter($array); @Martin

Answer (score 6):

**1st :** use `array_filter` to filter the empty element of  array

**2nd :** use `array_map` function to apply the `trim` function to `each value` inside the `array`

**3rd :** use `implode` to `break` the `array into string`

```
$array = array(' lastname ', ' email ','',' phone ');

$string= implode(" ", array_map("trim",array_filter($array)));

echo $string;
```

Answer (score 2):

> Trim the array elements using `trim` by `array_map` and finally do an
>   `array_filter` using `strlen` as the call-back.

```
$array = array(' lastname ', ' ',' email ', ' phone ');    

$new_arr = array_filter(array_map('trim',$array),'strlen');

$comma_separated = implode(" ", $new_arr);

echo $comma_separated;
```

Output

```
lastname email phone
```

See live [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ec3927f5c81a8b60535a8ee8c3995378685cee66)

Comment: hi what i asked is wrong i didnt notice a blank value in array what if `$array = array(' lastname ', ' ',' email ', ' phone '); how to only get element that is not empty 
`

Comment: @Martin May be you want to try this.. See updated answer